# Data report to pdf

Tags: vb6, report

Is it possible to convert Data report to a PDF from code?

As of now, i am printing Data report to a PDF printer from Data report print button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is technically possible, but you would need to either know or find the pdf file format and it would be a huge (I wouldn't do it) headache. The easiest solution is to find a control or library that works for you. There are several such as pdf.ocx. I used one many years ago and don't even remember the name any more as it was a very short lived project.